# Tensor products of permutation representations of symmetric groups.

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the following fact which must be classical (which makes it harder, for me, to track a reference down).  I am interested because there are similar (more complicated) statements about the cohomology of symmetric groups.

If $P$ is a partition, namely $p_{1} + \cdots + p_{k} = n$, we let $\rho_{P}$ denote 
the permutation representation of $S_{n}$, induced up from the trivial representation of $S_{P}$.

If $P$ and $Q$ are partitions of $n$ then consider any matrix $\hat{A}$ with nonnegative integer entries such that the entries
of $i$th row of $A$ add up to $p_{i}$ and those of the $j$th column of $A$ add up to $q_{j}$.  Then the entries of $\hat{A}$
form another partition of $n$, which we call $A$ and say that $A$ is a product-refinement of $P$ and $Q$.  For example if $P = Q = 1 + 2$ then two possibilities for $\hat{A}$ are $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Proposition: If $\rho_{P}$ and $\rho_{Q}$ are permutation representations of $S_n$ then $\rho_{P} \otimes \rho_{Q} \cong \bigoplus_{A} \rho_{A},$
where the sum is over $A$ which are product-refinements of $P$ and $Q$.

Questions: 1) what is the reference for this fact?  and 2) what is standard terminology (for product-refinement in particular)?

Comment: The "Frobenius characteristic" is an isomorphism between the space of class functions of $S_n$ and the homogeneous symmetric functions of degree $n$. It sends the character of $\rho_P$ to the product of complete sums $h_P=h_{P_1} \cdot h_{P_2} \cdots $. By transport of structure it gives a new product on the symmetric functions of degree $n$. 

So you might find some references for this result by looking for "Kronecker products of complete sum symmetric functions". 

Comment: I meant "It gives a new product on the symmetric functions of degree $n$, called the Kronecker product of symmetric functions." (or sometimes "internal product of symmetric functions").

Comment: Is the above proposition remain true over positive characteristic? Since the exercise in Richard Stanley's book uses character of permutation module over char 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi Dev,

It looks to me like a proof of this fact is given in the answer to Exercise 7.84(b) of Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, volume 2, along with a reference to Example I.7.23(e), page 131, of I. G. Macdonald's Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials (2nd edition).